# *Actually not, it's the other way round.* or *Actually, no, it's the other way round.*

Tags: negation

Are "actually not" and "actually, no" interchangeable in any context?

FOR EXAMPLE:
Tom: The Sun rotates around Earth
Steve: *Actually not, it's the other way round.* or *Actually, no, it's the other way round.*

The natives I asked said that the latter is preferred. But they didn't say why.
And one native says, e.g. that the sentence  *Is this sweater blue?* can be replied to with both *Actually not, it's red.* and *Actually, no; it's red.*

So how to be able to tell when those expressions can be used?

Comment: _Actually not_ is just a short way of saying _Actually it does not_ or _is not_. _Actually, no_ is just the normal answer _No_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting
  I feel like what you're saying means that when one can be use the other one can as well, right?

Comment: I don't find _actually not_ very idiomatic. I think it would be more natural to say _Actually it doesn't [rotate round the Earth]_ or _it's not [blue]_.

Answer (score -1):

"No" can be a response to a question or an imperative statement in its own right:

> -Can I have a drink?
> -No.

"Not" is not meant to be used that way, although it may be occasionally used in a deliberately subversive way:

> -Can I have a drink or not?
> -Not. (***this is not good grammar, but may be said for humourous, or sarcastic, emphatic effect.***)

So, the correct word choice for your example is '*no*', because it is a clause in its own right.

'No' and 'not' have specific uses and are not normally interchangeable.

We use **no** before a noun phrase.

> eg "*No swimming in the lake!*"

We use **not** with any other phrase or clause.

> eg "*Swimming in the lake is not allowed*".